# What's a good way to capture member variable by value in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

```
struct myclass {
    myclass(){}
    myclass(int qx):z(qx){   }
    std::function<void()> create() {
        auto px = [z](){
            std::cout << z << std::endl;
        };
        return px;
    }
    int z;
};

myclass my;
my.z = 2;
auto func = my.create();
func();
my.z = 3;
func();
```

This code will compile in gcc 4.6.3, which will do the correct thing to make a copy of member variable `z`, and both print will get `2`. In gcc 4.8.2 this doesn't compile anymore..

```
error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
```

I wonder why this functionality was removed as it was quite useful.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can do this directly in C++11 (see @Nawaz's comment for a workaround). However, C++14 helps exactly in this instance, via [generalized lambda captures](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures):

```
auto px = [v = this->z]() // capture by value just ONE member variable
{ 
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
};
```

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct myclass {
    myclass(): z{} {}
    myclass(int qx): z(qx) {   }
    std::function<void()> create() {
        auto px = [v = this->z]() {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        };
        return px;
    }
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    myclass my;
    my.z = 2;
    auto func = my.create();
    func();
    my.z = 3;
    func();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58e50440564c5899)

Comment: Workaround: `auto z = this->z;  auto px = [z] { ... };`.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas can only capture members of the local scope in which they are declared. They can't capture member variables, by copy or by reference.

However, C++14's generalized lambda capture can get the job done:

```
auto px = [z = z](){
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
};
```

You could qualify the inner `z` with `this->z` to make it clear what you're doing.

If C++14 is not available, you can make the capture explicit by creating a temporary variable in your function, which will be captured:

```
auto z = this->z;
auto px = [z](){
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
};
```